# Basic boolean logic: why is the expression "True or False" True?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I don't see why the expression "True or False" evaluates as True.

Comment: The OR returns `true` if at least one of the sides is `true`, otherwise it returns `false`.

Comment: That's how the logical disjunction works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction

Answer (score 0):

The Boolean evaluation is a binary state. By using the OR operator you allow for both states to be valid. Thus it will always evaluate as True because the condition is met.

Comment: what's the condition?

Comment: @J.DF That one or more of the arguments is true.